# Execute a sequence of instructions without switching to another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I have written a MultiThread C++ Codes using boost.
I have the below code in my main thread:

```
while (!mInputQueue.empty() && mStartProcessJobs)
    mProcessJobs.wait(lock);
```

the second line should be executed immediately after the first line and context switching should not occur. How can I do this?

Comment: You cannot control when the OS decides on when to switch threads/processes except yielding

Comment: Read about the [Boost thread synchronization facilities](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I cannot use `lock`, because if I use `lock` before the `while`, the main thread goes to sleep after calling `wait` and the locked mutex cannot be unlocked.

Comment: @EdHeal I do not know anything about yielding! I will read about it!

Comment: If you have synchronization woes, check out Downey's [The little book of semaphores](http://www.greenteapress.com/semaphores).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of the jobs, you can use an asynchronous service provider.

Often these exist for asynchronous IO (e.g. sockets in non-blocking mode, IO completion ports on windows, libaio etc.)

Boost Asio harnesses all these interfaces (and some more, related to timers, platform specific handles or e.g. serial ports) into a service object. This enables you to run many jobs asynchronously, potentially all on a single thread. This means that there is **no context switching**.

Asio's `io_service` has several ways of posting/dispatching jobs. Depending on which you use, jobs might even execute *immediately* and *synchronously*.

I suggest you look at some of the samples, as it looks to be precisely what you need.

PS. There are other - more low-level - libraries outside of boost that have the same kind of features but I haven't used them. I think the most popular are libuv/libevent (IIRC)